# Invoking modal window in AngularJS Bootstrap UI changes the window's URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Well, it could be easily reproduced by the following steps:

- Navigate to the note.am website,
- Press on "Not Registered yet ?" href link

You can observe that it momentally changes the window URL to /home and than set back again.

Here is my module's configuration part:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl'});
      $routeProvider.when('/register', {templateUrl: 'partials/register.html', controller: 'registerCtrl'});
      $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'});
      **$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});**
}]);
```

Comment: Try having an empty href attribute on the link (not even just a #), or even remove the href attribute completely.

Comment: Wow, works as expected, many thanks!